# How do I update the values of this variable between modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I have module **"bot.js"** and in this module, it constantly checks for messages and assigns them to a variable (*db_users*). Since I run my app from **"app.js"**, and I pass the functions that continuously populates *db_users*, how do I get this information to **"app.js"**?

**Bot.js** is using an IRC function that stores user's messages.

```
var db_users = []
// I then populate db_users with the previous data that is already in mongodb 
// using a .find().exec() mongodb command.
bot.addListener('message', function (from, to, text) {
    userInfo.checkForUser(db_users);
    // checkForUser basically looks through the variable db_users to see if 
    // there is a username that matches the "from" parameter in the listener
    // If it's not there, push some user information into the db_users array
    // and create a new MongoDB record.
    }
```

So I have all this, but my main app is a website that can control this "bot" (It's not a spam bot, but a moderation/statistical bot), and I'm using a require function to use **"./bot.js"** in **"app.js"**

**app.js**

```
bot = require('./bot');
```

So how would I constantly use the data in bot.js, in app.js? I'm a little fuzzy on how modules work.

Yeah I could just put all of the contents of app.js in bot.js, but it would be too annoying to look through.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you learned about [`module.exports`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports)?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't really know how to use that here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `db_users` inside an object so that it's just a reference. Make changes to that reference instead. Then `export` that outer object. Now since `db_users` is just a reference, it'll always be a latest copy of whatever it refers to.

**bot.js**

```
var data = module.exports = {};
data.db_users = [];
bot.addListener('message', function (from, to, text) {
    userInfo.checkForUser(data.db_users);
    }
```

**app.js**

```
botData = require('./bot');
```

`botData.db_users` will always have the whatever latest changes were made to `data.db_users` in `bot.js`